# set value of input field by type and placeholder name from javascript table jquery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-table

I have a table that is dynamically generated from bootstrap and it contains a search field to filter results. The input search field is generated as such

**HTML**

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" >
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="text"][placeholder="Search"]').val("test");
});
```

I also tried adding the `form-control` as well to it and that did not work as well.

```
$('input[class="form-control"][type="text"][placeholder="Search"]').val("test");
```

[this jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9m8purtj/) actually works as it should, but I am suspecting the dynamic loading of the search field from the bootstrap table is not catching it.

Comment: I have a feeling this is not working due to the dynamic loading of the field

Comment: Perhaps it's a timing issue? if so, maybe wrap the call in a `setTimeout` and give it like 100 millisecond or something, perhaps you need to call `$('#table').bootstrapTable('refresh');` after setting the search value to force it to refresh data...

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the github source  code here: https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/blob/master/src/bootstrap-table.js, I found line 836 to be interesting, it seems that he is triggering the search update on the search text box `keyup` event so...

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('input[type="text"][placeholder="Search"]')
        .val("bootstrap")
        .trigger('keyup');
},0);
```

And ouila!

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/jchandra/s6g3r786/

Answer (score 0):

You can use searchText(data-search-text) option: When set search property, initialize the search text.

```
<table id="table" data-search="true" data-search-text="bootstrap">
```

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/s6g3r786/2/